# What is the difference between split() and explode()?

Tags: php, posix-ere

The PHP manual for [`split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) says

> This function has been ***DEPRECATED*** as
>   of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature
>   is highly discouraged...Use `explode()`
>   instead.

But I can't find a difference between `split()` and `explode()`. `join()` hasn't been deprecated, so what gives?

Comment: Split gives you string fragments, whereas explode gives you machine fragments. Eh, probably not ... :-)

Comment: @Peter Rowell: split gives you two strands of hair, whereas explode gives you shrapnel.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's been deprecated because

- `explode()` is substantially faster because it doesn't split based on a regular expression, so the string doesn't have to be analyzed by the regex parser
- `preg_split()` is faster and uses PCRE regular expressions for regex splits

`join()` and `implode()` are aliases of each other and therefore don't have any differences.

Comment: So they messed up when they named it, apparently? Sounds like it should have been called ereg_split().

Comment: @hopeseekr: PHP always messes up naming of functions ;) And yeah, I guess you could say that!

Answer (score 6):

[`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) uses regex, while [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) uses a fixed string.  If you do need regex, use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), which uses PCRE (the regex package now preferred across the PHP standard library).

Answer (score 2):

Both the functions are used to Split a string.

However, Split is used to split a string using a regular expression.

On the other hand, Explode is used to split a string using another string.

**E.g** explode (" this", "this is a string"); will return “**Is a string**”

**E.g** Split (" + ", "This+ is a string");

Answer (score 1):

In `split()` you can use regular expressions to split a string. Whereas `explode()` splits a string with a string.
[preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is a much faster alternative, should you need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Both are used to split a string into an array, but the difference is that `split()` uses pattern for splitting whereas `explode()` uses string. `explode()` is faster than `split()` because it doesn't match string based on regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` function splits the string into an array using a regular expression and returns an array.

The `explode()` function splits the string by string.

E.g:

```php
<?php
    $split_array=split(':','I:P:S');
    $explode_array=explode('and','I and P and S');
    print_r($split_array);
    print_r($explode_array);
?>
```

The result will be

```php
Array ( [0] => I [1] => P [2] => S ) 
Array ( [0] => I [1] => P [2] => S )
```

Note:The function split() was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0

Comment: Hi Johnny Come Lately!!

Comment: I am not sure I understand this answer.
I don't understand what is being illustrated, particularly with this: 
`$explode_array=split('and','I and P and S');` The line is also using the split() function...