# split vs. explode in php

Tags: php

What is the difference between `explode` and `split` in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between split() and explode()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640990/what-is-the-difference-between-split-and-explode)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) splits strings.

[<strike>`split`</strike>](http://www.php.net/split) (replaced with [`mb_split`](https://www.php.net/mb_split) in newer versions of PHP) also does this, except it has support for splitting using regular expressions.

[`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) also does this <strike>and is 25-50% faster</strike> and has support for much more powerful Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Comment: ok.in php5.3 split is not use,insteadof it preg_split is used

Answer (score 17):

`split` uses regular expressions, while `explode` works with delimiter characters. Using `split` is discouraged, because it become deprecated in PHP 5.3.

Comment: sir it may,in php 5.3 split use with preg_split().? may i right sir?

Comment: yes, you should use preg_split() if you want to split the string with regular expressions

Answer (score 5):

explode is generally faster than split ; but its not multibyte character safe.

We will use explode when we are absolutely guaranteed that our input is in single-byte character sets such as ISO-8859-1, and split when we are dealing with user input.

Answer (score 0):

Both split and explode function splits the string into the array but split is used to split a string using **regular expression** while explode is used to split a string using **another string**.